# Ruby webscraping csv encoding output

Tags: ruby, csv, character-encoding, web-scraping

I know it would be very basic for most of you but I didn't find an answer so I have to ask!:)

- The thing is that the output I receive in my webscraping CSV file returns strange characters, like \u00F3, etc. for Spanish accents. I'd probably need to do something at the end of my code where CSV is, but I don't know what.
- And the other thing is that I'm getting only one array where there should be one per every line of the website.

Thanks

CODE:

```
url= "(the url of th website)"
page= Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))



description= page.css('div.post-body.entry-content').each do |line|
body << line.text.strip
end


puts body


# CSV
CSV.open("hello.csv", "w") do |file|
file << [body]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it! actually I have to put the following to the end:

```
CSV.open("hello.csv", "w+:UTF-16LE:UTF-8") do |file|
file << body

end
```